# Symbols appearing at different scale in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, symbols

I've searched but couldn't find anything relevant to my situation. I made symbols in Ai and was able to replace them easily, they all appeared at the original scale when turned into a symbol. Then it stopped working: the new symbols I made would appear at a smaller scale.

I can use "reset transformation" to get them to go back to the original scale, but this is a pain as I have to do it for each one and I have a lot that I'm working with. Anyone know how to get the symbols to appear at their original scale?

I deleted the prefs but it didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

- Click one symbol instance on an artboard
- Menu: `Select > Same > Symbol Instance`
- Click the `Reset` button on the **Control Bar** across the top of the screen.

This will reset *all* the instances of *that* symbol to the original size of the symbol and remove any transformations which have been applied to the individual instances.

Repeat for each different symbol in use if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

A symbol is a container with content. Both can have a width and a height. Your content probably has a different scale now since you first scaled the symbols (while you should have scaled the content inside.

Now what you can do is, set the content to the same scale by going into the symbol and set a width or height at the same values if possible. NOTE: There seems no sollution to reset a symbol to it's original scale without dragging it back into your artboard.